# Order elements into different columns using separate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data from a "select all that apply" survey data and I now have something like this:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
answer <- c("apple, orange", "pinneaple, apple", "orange, pinneaple", "pinneaple, orange","apple")

df <- data.frame(ID,answer)

> df
  ID            answer
1  1     apple, orange
2  2  pinneaple, apple
3  3 orange, pinneaple
4  4 pinneaple, orange
5  5             apple
```

Now, I am trying to separate this and spread the results, for this I am using `separate` from `dplyr` and it does only partially what I am looking for:

```
df %>% 
  separate(answer, into = c("ans1", "ans2","ans3"), sep = ", ")

> df
  ID      ans1      ans2 ans3
1  1     apple    orange <NA>
2  2 pinneaple     apple <NA>
3  3    orange pinneaple <NA>
4  4 pinneaple    orange <NA>
5  5     apple      <NA> <NA>
```

Now, I would like to have the responses ordered. In the example that would be assigning  `ans1` to `apple` and so on, until we would end up with something like this:

```
> target_df
  ID  ans1   ans2      ans3
1  1 apple orange      <NA>
2  2 apple   <NA> pinneaple
3  3  <NA> orange pinneaple
4  4  <NA> orange pinneaple
5  5 apple   <NA>      <NA>
```

Is there a way to add this order attribute to the `separate` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows, although it does not use `separate`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
answer <- c("apple, orange", "pinneaple, apple", "orange, pinneaple", "pinneaple, orange","apple")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,answer)

df1 |> 
  separate_rows(answer) |> 
  mutate(value = answer, 
         value = str_replace_all(value, c("apple" = "ans1", "orange" = "ans2", "pinneaple" = "ans3"))) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = answer)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>      ID ans1  ans2   ans3     
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>    
#> 1     1 apple orange <NA>     
#> 2     2 apple <NA>   pinneaple
#> 3     3 <NA>  orange pinneaple
#> 4     4 <NA>  orange pinneaple
#> 5     5 apple <NA>   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works just great, I had to add ```sep = ", "``` to ```sepparate``` beacuse I did not have one word answers (even if I used this in the example), but it works, thanks!